# Getting error "does not have a CFBundleName key with a non-zero length string value in its Info.plist"

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am working with xcode 8.3 and swift 3.1

I getting error when I run the project like

> does not have a CFBundleName key with a non-zero length string value in its Info.plist

I  don't have made any change in plist.

[image]

Comment: Try to add valid provisioning and certificate to run the project on your device.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani it's not working on simulator also

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into this issue myself, and although the error states the issue lies with `CFBundleName`, it was fixed by adding `CFBundleDisplayName` and a string value to the main app target, as well as the extension target.

See below:

```
MainApp/Info.plist
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>My App</string>

AppExtension/Info.plist
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>My App</string>
```